# Equivalent of a Hindi proverb: Only a jeweller can identify a diamond

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-request, proverbs

There’s a saying in Hindi:

> “Only a jeweller can identify a diamond.”

Example:

> The master found the art hidden inside Viddiya and made her a famous lyricist. It’s true **only a jeweller can identify a diamond.**

The meaning is it requires an expert to understand good quality of somebody or something.

I think the translation conveys the meaning of the proverb, but I want similar proverb originated in the U.K.

Comment: Does it mean "only an expert knows if something is valuable" or is it more like "an expert can see good qualities non-experts can't see because the expert knows what to look for" or "only an expert can tell the difference between a diamond and a fake gem"?

Comment: Not directly equivalent, but the noun phrase "diamond in the rough" often appears in examples like the one you used. It just refers to a valuable thing that could easily be overlooked, but doesn't say anything about who may or may not be able to find it.

Answer (score 3):

I've considered this list of [680 English proverbs](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/proverbs.html), and to the best of my knowledge, I don't think there is a direct equivalent English proverb or saying that would be interchangeable with the one you have translated.

The English saying "it takes one to know one" means that one type of person can recognise another of the same ilk - however it is almost always used in a *negative* context, often as a retort to someone calling out a negative quality in them.

There is a saying that someone can be "like putty in the hands of" someone else, and this can be used positively to suggest that someone like a teacher was able to help 'shape' someone into something great, likening it to a potter turning clay into a piece of art. Again though, it can be used negatively, suggesting that a person is easily-influenced rather than willing to learn.

Some Biblical proverbs are well known, but are not always as recognisable as sayings. Also, you might not think of these as 'English' proverbs. However you might want to consider Proverbs 20:5 which likens a person's thoughts to the water deep in a well and says that an expert can draw them up.

As you say, your translation is good and the meaning is conveyed perfectly. An English speaker would certainly understand it. And, if spoken by a native Hindi speaker, I think it would be fairly clear when you say "it's true" that what follows must be a known saying in your own native language.

Comment: ***It takes one to know one*** is a fairly generic saying. There's also the more specific [***Set a thief to catch a thief***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/setting+a+thief+to+catch+a+thief), but in some ways that's almost the "opposite" of OP's version, in that we can assume *his* "jeweller" is an honest upright citizen, whereas a jewel thief (and his "fence") are criminals.

Comment: Your answer is great, no argument.  There even seems to be a sentiment exactly opposite this.  To misquote a couple of examples, "I don't know much art, but I know what I like." or "It doesn't take a great actor to recognize a bad one."  The idea that only an expert can tell you the truth may be wise, but it doesn't really fit (at least the US) culturally.